# Inner Product on $C^1[a,b]$

Tags: hilbert-spaces, inner-products

> For a continuously differentiable function $f$ on $[-\pi, \pi]$, prove that $$\Bigg|\int_{-\pi}^\pi \Big(f(x) \cos(x) - f'(x)\sin(x)\Big)\,dx\Bigg| \leq \sqrt{2\pi}\Bigg\{\int_{-\pi}^\pi \Big(|f(x)|^2 + |f'(x)|^2\Big) \, dx\Bigg\}^{1/2}$$

My try:
$$ \left| \int_{-\pi}^\pi \Big(f(x) \cos(x) - f'(x)\sin(x)\Big)\,dx \right| \leq \int_{-\pi}^\pi \Big|f(x) \cos(x) - f'(x)\sin(x)\Big| \, dx $$

Now, I am supposed to use some Inner Product on $C^1[a,b]$ here but I don't know which one to use and how. It would be great to have a hint. Thanks.

Comment: Try $\langle f,g\rangle_* = \langle f,g\rangle_2 + \langle f',g'\rangle_2$. Figure out what $g$ must be so you can express the above in terms of this inner product. Compute norms using the '*' inner product.

Comment: And use the [Cauchy-Schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy–Schwarz_inequality): $|\left<f, g\right>| \le \lVert f \rVert \lVert g \rVert$, where the norms are induced by the inner product itself.

Comment: @copper.hat: Taking $g(x)=cos(x)$ and applying Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality gives the desired result. Thanks.

Comment: @ComFreek: Thanks a ton.